# Clear interval not working inside an if statement in a function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a simple **countdown timer** which dynamically stops once met a falsy condition. (*implemented setTimeout to demo when countdown should stop*)

I don't usually use `setInterval/clearInterval` thing so I researched and tried some stuffs I've found and still doesn't work.

I believe there are just few discrepancy in here.

Here is the code.

```js
var intervals;
function startTimer(isStarted) {
  intervals = setInterval(_countDown, 1000);
  var requestTimer = 60,
      seconds;

  function _countDown() {
    seconds = parseInt(requestTimer % 60, 10);
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

    console.log(seconds);

    if (--requestTimer < 0) {
      requestTimer = 60;
    }
  }

  if (!isStarted) {
    console.log("timer now should stop!!!!!!");
    clearInterval(intervals);
  }
}

startTimer(true);
setTimeout(startTimer, 3000);
```

```html
<h1>Open the console to see the timer.</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are actually starting the interval twice since you call startTimer-method twice (the two last lines of code). That is why a single clearTimeout won't cut it anymore. Also you set the interval before declaring the function it is supposed to execute. So I would simplify things like so:

```
var interval;
function startTimer() {      
  var requestTimer = 60,
      seconds;

  function _countDown() {
    seconds = parseInt(requestTimer % 60, 10);
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

    console.log(seconds);

    if (--requestTimer < 0) {
      requestTimer = 60;
    }
  }

  interval = setInterval(_countDown, 1000);
}

startTimer();
setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("timer now should stop!!!!!!");
    clearTimeout(interval);
}, 3000);
```

Comment: **Also you set the interval before declaring the function it is supposed to execute**
I disagree on this one it will still work even if its declared before the intervl..
also notice that I have a parameter in the startTimer() which I planned to use in a success function that will supposed to receives a boolean value.

Comment: I was out of my mind.. I didn't think that I could just call the function to stop the interval on failed function

Comment: You can disagree if you want, but just because you have setInterval doen'st mean you can "call" a function or use a variable before it has been declared.

Comment: **use a variable before it has been declared** this is different story then, when it comes to variable heirarchy is really is a must

Comment: anyway thanks for the idea mate ! somehow it help :)

Comment: No problem, accept the answer if it was what you needed.